# Textbox Input Validation

Tags: jquery, validation, input, textbox

I have the following jQuery code which will allow me to only input numbers into textboxes:

```
$('.numbersOnly').keyup(function () {
    if (this.value != this.value.replace(/[^0-9\.]/g, '')) {
    this.value = this.value.replace(/[^0-9\.]/g, '');
}
});
```

I am looking to add some additional validation to this to allow a range of 0 to 10 and to three decimal places.  Is this the correct form of the code I should be using?

```
$('.numbersOnly').keyup(function () {
    if (this.value != this.value.replace(/[^([0-9]|1[0])\.(0[0-9][0-9]|1[0][0])$]/g, '')) {
    this.value = this.value.replace(/[^0-9\.]/g, '');
}
});
```

Comment: No it does not work - sorry, I should have added that.

Comment: Not answering the question, but in order to test your pattern, you should use [`test`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/test?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=JavaScript%2FReference%2FGlobal_Objects%2FRegExp%2Ftest) method of the `Regexp` object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The regex in your question is not valid. The pattern requested is more complex than just "a number". Instead of checking a *non*-matching pattern with

```
if (this.value != this.value.replace(...
```

I would suggest using a matching one and

```
if ("" != this.value.replace(...
```

This matches your need: `([0-9]|10)(\.[0-9][0-9][0-9])?`

Note: the replace in the last line does not necessarily solve the problem, as it does in your first example.

Comment: I am not very experienced with regex - I can't get my new piece of code to validate!  I've tested the regex in RegexPal and it works but when I apply it - http://jsfiddle.net/h6skv/ - it does not work!

Comment: I cleaned it up a bit: http://jsfiddle.net/h6skv/1/. Again - it will remove letters and spaces but wont fix the format if it doesn't comply with the pattern

Comment: Ah, I see were I went wrong there.  Is there any way to limit it to only allow three numbers after the decimal and to stop accepting any input after that?

Comment: It's a bit complicated, since if there's an error I don't really know where it was (if the user input 15 did he mean 1 or 5?). Here's a suggestion: [truncate after 5 characters](http://jsfiddle.net/h6skv/2/)

Comment: Actually that works perfectly for my needs!  The maximum I would like entered is 10 so that allows someone to add 10.00

Comment: Though it would still allow 10.99 for above reason

Comment: So it does - but as the max value will be ten, I don't see this becoming an issue as they only want the decimal places for the zero to nine entries.